# How to do discrete optimization with python

Tags: python, math, mathematical-optimization, data-science, discrete-mathematics

I have a discrete optimization problem similar to

Y=3X1+2X2 (a sample one)

Minimize Y such that there are some constraints for X1 and X2 like
X1 +X2 >20

X1 can take values from {5,10,15,25,85}
X2 can take values from {20,25,5,40,10} etc

How can do this problem with python

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I want to find the values of X1 and X2 such that it should give the minimum value of Y and also X1 and X2 should satisfy the constraints(X1+X2>20) . How can i do this with branch and bound algorithm(or any algorithm) in python. I think it is a discrete optimization problem since X1 belongs to a set {5,10,15,25,85} and X2 belongs to {20,25,5,40,10}

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html#scipy.optimize.fmin

Comment: @SreejaP Basically you want to get the two values that doon't add up to twenty in the zipped (x1,x2)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I go through this before. It is for continuous input. Here the problem is my inputs are discrete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easily modeled with binary variables:

[image]

Similar for X2. Most textbooks about integer programming will mention this. Your teacher can probably recommend a few books.

Sometimes SOS1 variables (Special Ordered Sets of Type 1) are suggested for this construct. Some solvers support this. I typically use binary variables for this type of table lookup.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This solution is working. Now i am facing another issue.

Comment: My intputs are X1 and X2. (representing products). Each product has two parameters its price and rating . I have to choose from product list X1 and from product list X2 such that the total cost should be minimum and should satisfy the rating constraints.